# SQL Statement:How to retrieve the start date corresponding to a record with no end date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have employees who start and stop using a service. This service is recorded every year as they are eligible to start the service starting of the year and renew ending of the year. How do i get a start date for which they started in the beginning rather than the most recent of 01/01/2019. In the attached image i would like to get 01-Mar-13 as start date and 01-Jan-00 as end date since the employee had continuous service since 01-Mar-13.

The Employee number is another column available to identify the employee.

[image: Click for image of dates in Database]

Comment: Which other columns are available to help with this?  Presumably there must be an employee identifier column?

Comment: Correct. Employee Number is available.

Comment: Wouldn't this then be as simple as `MIN(START_DATE) ... GROUP BY employee_number`?

Comment: Nope. Min of start-date gives us 01-JUL-11 and thats not what i am looking for. I am looking for 01-MAR-13 since the employee stopped the service in 28-APR-12 and restarted service in 01-MAR-13. I want the day from which there was continuous service.

Comment: So, you want 01-Mar-13 since that is the start of the current continuous service? How do you identify that row as the one from which there was continuous service? What are the other rows? Is this whole example from the same employee? I think we need to see at least the employee id column and whatever other column differentiates Mar 13 row from the others.

Comment: Yes. we do have employee id as the identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . Identify where the periods of employeement begin.  Then you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select empid,
       max(case when prev_stop_date is null or
                     prev_stop_date <> start_date - 1
                then start_date
            end) as start_date,
      max(stop_date) as stop_date
from (select t.*,
             lag(stop_date) over (partition by empid order by start_date) as prev_stop_date
      from t
     ) t
group by empid;
```